# How many grandchildren does Joe Biden have?

Tags: joe-biden

Twitter account @EndWokeness [has claimed](https://twitter.com/EndWokeness/status/1614439661325230081) (in a tweet with almost 5 million views, 6000 retweets, 500+ quotes and 30k+ likes) that Joe Biden has a seventh granddaughter

> This is Joe Biden’s granddaughter
>
> He still pretends she doesn’t exist despite the fact that DNA tests have proven that Hunter is her father

This doesn't match some reporting - e.g. [Yahoo Insider](https://news.yahoo.com/joe-bidens-granddaughter-naomi-getting-142053960.html) says "Meet his 6 grandchildren"

Does Joe Biden have a granddaughter from Hunter Biden, the existence of which he denies?

Comment: If "DNA tests have proven that Hunter is her father", this suggests that Hunter most likely isn't in the child's life, and neither is Joe Biden. So it seems you'd inevitably get into the semantics of what it means to "pretend someone doesn't exist" if you don't have any relationship with them (and why would the media include her in positive article about his grandchildren if there's no relationship between them?). There are about 8 billion people whose existence I don't generally acknowledge, not to "pretend" or "suppress", but just because their individual existence has no bearing on my life.

Comment: A better title might be "Is Joe Biden hiding a grandchild?" That seems to be scandalous, possibly notable, claim being made in the tweet. I was thinking about adding "illegitimate", but that almost makes it a push Q.

Comment: @OwenReynolds "Does J.B. have a granddaughter he doesn't maintain a relationship with?"

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- But this is Skeptics, where claims have to be notable. They have to have a "that can't be true" quality.

Comment: @NotThatGuy the biological granddaughter of the president of the United States is not one of 8 billion random people. Given Biden's stated love for his family (much as most people have!) it would be strange indeed for Biden to believe what you said: "There are about 8 billion people whose existence I don't generally acknowledge, not to "pretend" or "suppress", just because their individual existence has no bearing on my life." Per my answer https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/56713/4301 Biden has acknowledged his granddaughter on 28 July 2023. He is trying to protect her as she is 4 yrs old.

Answer (score 49):

**Joe Biden has 7 biological (and legal) grand-children.**

Between Joe Biden's four children (two of whom are deceased), there are six *legitimate* grand-children:

- Two from Beau Biden: Natalie and Robert Hunter II
- Four from Hunter Biden: Naomi, Finnegan, Maisy, and Beau

In addition, Hunter Biden has been declared the biological and legal father of a fifth child (therefore Joe Biden's seventh grand-child), identified in court as "NJR".

The court case establishing paternity and agreeing maintenance payments was widely reported in late 2019 / early 2020, e.g. [CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/01/27/politics/hunter-biden-paternity-case-child-support/index.html), [CNBC](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/12/10/hunter-biden-paternity-case-childs-mother-wants-ukraine-money-details.html), [New York Post](https://nypost.com/2019/12/12/hunter-biden-faces-deposition-in-paternity-suit/).

Comment: The implication here being that, no, the media is *not* suppressing her existence, because they reported it at the time it was first made public.

Comment: @F1Krazy I'm not convinced the "cover-up" part is either answerable or noteworthy, so was mainly including the press coverage as evidence that she exists; but yes, it's not exactly a secret.

Comment: Given that a core part of the claim is "He still pretends she doesn’t exist", an answer should probably also include what he's said on the matter, if anything, or why this isn't a noteworthy claim.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be answering the question: "Does Joe Biden have a granddaughter from Hunter Biden, *the existence of which he denies*?". Since it is self evident and non controversial that he has at least one granddaughter from Hunter, the question is more about whether he still denies it, and your answer doesn't address that bit. Has Biden ever denied that this child is his granddaughter _after_ the court case? (edit: just saw the original version of the question which was different and fits your answer better, but it would still be nice to answer the second claim)

Comment: "denies" is an embellishment by OP, though. "He still pretends she doesn’t exist" doesn't entail denial; it just entails not bringing up the matter (as long as ideologically opposed media doesn't bring it up either, at least).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not talking about something is not the same as pretending it doesn't exist.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "He still pretends she doesn’t exist" may or may not entail denial. It's far too vague to know what exactly they meant, which is kind of the problem with such statements: anyone who wants to see Biden as the bad guy interprets it as him explicitly lying about it, even if the truth in the statement may just be that he hasn't commented publicly on it. And because it's so vague, you can't really "expose" the person making the statement as a liar, even if their statement is somewhere between wildly irresponsible and intentionally misleading.

Comment: @F1Krazy just because something happened in the past doesn't mean it's not happening right now.

Comment: @user1271772 Just because people make vague claims of others acting maliciously doesn't mean we should dig through every news report an organisation has ever published looking for justification for that. The fact that they reported on it sufficiently refutes the claim that they're suppressing it, at which point anyone who wants to argue otherwise would need to back up their claim with compelling evidence (but even if they didn't report on it, that would be journalistic freedom, and one could try to argue it's bad/biased journalism, but it's not automatically "suppression").

Comment: NotThatGuy: no one here said anything that your last comment suggests we did.

Comment: Hunter Biden had denied fathering the child, which colloquially is sometimes described as 'pretending the child doesn't exist' (i.e. isn't his), until the court said it was biologically his. Whether or not Hunter continues to pretend the kid doesn't exist (i.e. have a relationship with the child and acknowledge paternity) I don't know. To what extent President Biden has pretended the kid doesn't exist, I also do not know. But the tweet seems to be mostly correct, at least as far as Hunter Biden is concerned, and unproven, as far as President Biden is concerned.

Comment: @user1271772 ???. The question (originally) asked whether mainstream media are "trying to suppress or ignore the fact of her existence" (i.e. acting maliciously), and you replied to a comment to say the media having reported on it "doesn't mean [suppression is] not happening right now". Those words do suggest that suppression is likely happening, so I just added the responsible caveat that we don't have any reason to believe that suppression is happening, and every reason to believe it isn't happening. So I'm not sure which part of my comment you think doesn't reflect what others said.

Answer (score 30):

The claim by the EndWokeness Twitter account seems to be false. The EndWokeness claim of "denies" is difficult to refute because they did not cite nor show where Joe Biden actively said "I do not have seven grandkids" or something similar.

Finding sources which are not complete trash or celebrity gossip is tough.

[People.com](https://people.com/politics/all-about-joe-biden-grandchildren/) says:

> DNA testing later confirmed Hunter as the father. During the suit, a motion was filed to keep the child's identifying information hidden from the public in order to protect the child during the 2020 presidential election.

So per a court order the grandchild's information was being kept private. The most logical explanation is that Joe Biden is following the court order and the wishes of that side of the family to keep them out of the limelight.

Some background on the paternity test and child support case is at [Judge signs order declaring paternity in Hunter Biden case](https://www.texarkanagazette.com/news/2020/jan/08/judge-signs-order-declaring-paternity-hunter-biden/).

Comment: Also possible that he was never told the 7th grandchilds name seeing as his sons paternity cases has nothing in particular to do with him.

Answer (score 1):

Until July 28, 2023, Joe Biden did not publicly acknowledge the existence of his seventh grandchild, who was age four at the time. Many news stories described the situation as Joe Biden **"not acknowledging"** his [seventh grandchild](https://www.npr.org/2023/07/28/1190875393/biden-grandchild-navy) (as reported by NPR) rather than "denying her existence, prior to that date in July 2023:

> President Biden publicly acknowledged his seventh grandchild, a
> 4-year-old named Navy Joan Roberts, for the first time on Friday,
> capping a month of questions about why he had seemingly excluded the
> little girl from his tight family circle.

This marked a change from 28 April 2023, when [Biden did not mention his 7th grandchild](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-iwMedNIq4) during a "Take Your Child to Work Day" event at the White House:

> "I have six grandchildren. And I’m crazy about them. And I speak to
> them every single day."

A [New York Times article published on 1 July 2023](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/01/us/politics/hunter-biden-daughter-arkansas.html), reports that

> "In strategy meetings in recent years, aides have been told that the
> Bidens have six, not seven, grandchildren."